# React/Next, Express app using passport.js logs into account without being registered?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) as my database to store the users for my app.

However, I just noticed while my app prevents users who have registered to register again, I can't figure out why it is authenticating users who are not in MongoDB to begin with??

I am using [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) for authentication, the [local strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) specifically:

This is my model:

```
/* eslint-disable no-var */
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var emailValidator = require('email-validator')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt') // hashing function dedicated for passwords

const SALT_ROUNDS = 12

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        index: { unique: true },
        validate: {
            validator: emailValidator.validate,
            message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid email address`
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        index: { unique: true },
        minlength: 8
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

UserSchema.pre('save', async function preSave(next) {
    var user = this
    var hash
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next()
    try {
        hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS)
        user.password = hash
        return next()
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
})

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function comparePassword(candidate) {
    return bcrypt.compare(candidate, this.password)
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Here is my auth file,

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username', passwordField: 'password'  }, async(username, password, done) => {
    try {
        var user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username }).exec();
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username or password' })
        }
        var passwordOk = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!passwordOk) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username or password' })
        }
        return done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err)
    }
}))

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user._id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
    try {
        var user = await UserModel.findById(id).exec();
        return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err)
    }
})

module.exports = {
    initialize: passport.initialize(),
    session: passport.session(),
    setUser: (req, res, next) => {
        res.locals.user = req.user;
        next();
    }
}
```

And this is my central app file on the server.

```
const express = require('express');

require('dotenv').config()

const nextJS = require('next');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var auth = require('./lib/auth');
var cors = require('cors')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes')
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8016

const { isBlockedPage, isInternalUrl } = require('next-server/dist/server/utils');

function NODE_ENVSetter(ENV) {
    var environment,
        environments = {
            'production': () => {
                environment = process.env.PRODUCTION_DB_DSN;
                return environment;
            },
            'test': () => {
                environment = process.env.TEST_DB_DSN;
                return environment;
            },
            'default': () => {
                environment = process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN;
                console.log("environment ", environment);
                return environment;
            },
        };
    (environments[ENV] || environments['default'])();

    return environment
}

var db = NODE_ENVSetter('development')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    // Set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

    // Log error
    console.error(err.stack)

    // Render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500)

    // Default error message by HTTP code
    res.render('error', {
        title: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status),
        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status)
    })
}

async function start() {
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
    const app = nextJS({ dev });
    const server = express();
    await app.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
            mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

            mongoose.connection
                .on('connected', () => {
                    console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${db}`)
                })
                .on('error', err => {
                    console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`)
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        })

    server.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))
    server.use(bodyParser.json())
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    server.use(morgan('dev'))

    server.use(cookieParser())

    server.use(session({
        secret: 'very secret 12345',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    }));

    server.use(auth.initialize);
    server.use(auth.session);
    server.use(auth.setUser);

    server.use(cors())
    server.use('/users', require('./users'))
    server.use('/images', require('./images'))

    // Redirect all requests to main entrypoint pages/index.js
    server.get('/*', async(req, res, next) => {
        try {
            // @NOTE code duplication from here
            // https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/cc6fe5fdf92c9c618a739128fbd5192a6d397afa/packages/next-server/server/next-server.ts#L405
            const pathName = req.originalUrl;
            if (isInternalUrl(req.url)) {
                return app.handleRequest(req, res, req.originalUrl)
            }

            if (isBlockedPage(pathName)) {
                return app.render404(req, res, req.originalUrl)
            }

            // Provide react-router static router with a context object
            // https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering
            req.locals = {};
            req.locals.context = {};
            const html = await app.renderToHTML(req, res, '/', {});

            // Handle client redirects
            const context = req.locals.context;
            if (context.url) {
                return res.redirect(context.url)
            }

            // Handle client response statuses
            if (context.status) {
                return res.status(context.status).send();
            }

            // Request was ended by the user
            if (html === null) {
                return;
            }

            app.sendHTML(req, res, html);
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    });

    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.status(404).send('404 - Not Found!');
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
    server.use(errorHandler, function(error, req, res, next) {
        res.json({ message: error.message })
    })

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    });
}

start();
```

And this is my client component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Loader, Dimmer, Transition, Button, Form, Grid, Header, Message, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Link from 'next/link';
import { login } from 'next-authentication'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { logInUser } from '../../store/reducers/users/index'

class LoginForm extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
   fadeUp: 'fade up',
   duration: 500,
   username: '',
   password: '',
   usernameError: false,
   passwordError: false,
   formSuccess: false,
   formError: false,
   isLoading: true,
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this)
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false })
 }

 handleChange(event) {
  var { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
   [name]: value
  })
 }

 handleBlur() {
  var { username } = this.state;
  var error = false;

  var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if ((!username.match(mailFormat)) || (!username)) {
   error = true;
   this.setState({ usernameError: true });
  } else {
   this.setState({ usernameError: false, });
  }
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
   isLoading: true
  })

  var error = false;
  var { username, password, isLoading } = this.state;
  var { history } = this.props

  var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

  if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
   this.setState({ usernameError: true });
   error = true;
  } else {
   this.setState({ usernameError: false });
  }

  if (password.length < 8) {
   this.setState({ passwordError: true });
   error = true;
  } else {
   this.setState({ passwordError: false })
  }

  if (error) {
   this.setState({ formSuccess: false });
   return;
  }

  return window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password })
  })
   .then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response)
    if (response.ok) {

     const { token } = response.clone();

     const loginOptions = {
      token,
      cookieOptions: { expires: 1 },
      callback: () => history.push('/profile')
     }

     setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.logInUser()
      login(loginOptions);
     }, 5000)

     this.setState({
      username: '' , password: '', formError: false, formSuccess: true, isLoading: false
     })
     return response.json();
    } else if (!response.ok) {
     if (response.status === 404) {
      console.log("response.status ", response.status);
       console.log("isLoading 2", isLoading) 
      this.setState({
       formError: true, formSuccess: false, isLoading: false
      });
      return;
     }
    }

    return response;
   })
   .catch(err => console.dir(err))

 }

 render() {
  var { username, password, usernameError, passwordError, formSuccess, formError, duration, isLoading } = this.state;
  console.log("LoginForm this.props ", this.props);

  var { isLoggedIn } = this.props;

 console.log("isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
  (formSuccess === true) ? isLoggedIn = true : isLoggedIn = false;

  return (<div className='login-form'> {

  }<style>{`body > div, body > div > div, body > div > div > div.login-form { height: 100%;}`} </style>

   <Grid textAlign='center'
    style={{ height: '100%' }}
    verticalAlign='middle' >
    <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
     <Header as='h2'
      color='teal'
      textAlign='center'>
      Log-in to your account
     </Header>

     <Form size='large'
      onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      error={formError}>


      <Segment stacked>
       <Form.Input fluid icon='user'
        iconPosition='left'
        placeholder='E-mail address, e.g. joe@schmoe.com'
        name='username'
        value={username}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={usernameError}
       />

       <Transition visible={usernameError}
        animation='scale'
        duration={duration}>
        <Message error content='username_Email is in incorrect format e.g. joe@schmoe.com' />
       </Transition>

       <Form.Input fluid icon='lock'
        iconPosition='left'
        placeholder='Password'
        name='password'
        value={password}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={passwordError}
       />

       <Transition visible={passwordError}
        animation='scale'
        duration={duration}>
        <Message error content='Password is incorrect, please try again.' />
       </Transition>

       <Button color='teal'
        fluid size='large'
        disabled={!username || !password}>
        Log-in
       </Button>

       <Transition visible={formError}
        unmountOnHide={true}
        animation='scale'
        duration={duration}>

        {isLoading ?
         <Dimmer active inverted>
          <Loader />
         </Dimmer>
         :
         <Message
          error
          centered="true" header='This email does not exist...'
          content='Please re-enter another email address, or  click the link below to register.' />
        }
       </Transition>



       <Transition visible={formSuccess}
        unmountOnHide={true}
        animation='scale'
        duration={duration}>
        {isLoading ?
         <Dimmer active inverted>
          <Loader />
         </Dimmer>
         :
         <Message
          success
          header='Your have successfully logged in.'
          content='Welcome to Hillfinder!' />
        }
       </Transition>

      </Segment>
     </Form>

     {formError ?
      <Transition visible={formError}
       animation='scale'
       duration={1000}>
       <Message>
        <Link href="/register">
         <a>Register</a>
        </Link> </Message>
      </Transition>
      : null
     }
    </Grid.Column> </Grid> </div>
  )
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 console.log("state ", state);
 const { users } = state
 console.log("users ", users);
 const { isLoggedIn } = users
  console.log("isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
 return { isLoggedIn }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ logInUser }, dispatch)

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the whole thing but the bug may be in here:

```
var user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username }).exec();
```

With async/await you do not execute the promise that way, you just await it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Another point is combining bcrypt with passportJS, which I don't think is the right approach, see docs:

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/#configuration

PassportJS has its own built in hashing so it might get confused! :)